# cannot apply 'android-reporting' in gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

When I put `apply plugin: 'android-reporting'` in my project level build.gradle file as suggested [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line), gradle sync fails throwing

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add extension with name 'android', as there is an extension already registered with that name.

Can somebody help what could be happening here. I am at latest version of gradle plugin.

Comment: make sure you put this line in the end of all

Comment: @GianhTran I have put at end itself.

Answer (score 4):

You need to apply it at the end of the root build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue from applying an android plugin via an allPlugins block. If you change this to subprojects it might fix your issue